# Characteristic of $\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_9[x]$?

Tags: ring-theory

Is this characteristic 9? Since $char(\Bbb Z_3)$ = 3 and $char(\Bbb Z_9[x]) = 9$?

I just wanted to make sure I'm not overthinking this and that I'm understanding this correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. In fact, in general we have that if $\operatorname{char}(R) = r$ and $\operatorname{char}(S) = s$, then $\operatorname{char}(R\times S) = \operatorname{lcm}(r, s)$.

Answer (score 1):

The identity of $\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_9$ is $([1]_3,[1]_9)$.

Since the characteristic of a ring $R$ is the smallest positive integer such that $n.1_R=0_R$

So $n([1]_3,[1]_9)=([0],[0])\implies n[1]_3=0;n[1]_9=0\implies n=9$ (since order of $[1]_9 $in $\Bbb Z_9$ is $9$)